# Showing turing machines exist for the following

Tags: complexity-theory, boolean-expression, turing-machines

I'm struggling to understand a question I've been given. The question asks:
Let A be a boolean formula in n variables. There are 2^n different combinations of assigning
values to the variables. Consider the problem of deciding whether (strictly) more than 2^(n−1)
of these assignments satisfy the formula A. We will call the language that corresponds to this
decision problem, L.

From this I can tell that if x_1, x_2, ..., x_n are the n variables which can be either true or false. I understand why there would be 2^n different assignings for the formula, as each variable can be assigned 1 of 2 values. But then what is A exactly, is it an assignment such as A=(x_1 ∨ x_2 ∨ ... x_n). But then the later part of the question doesn't make any sense. Can someone please explain in more detail what it means by "deciding whether (strictly) more than 2^(n−1) of these assignments satisfy the formula A"?

The question is then to show that there exists a turing machine M and polynomials T and p, with the following properties:

• For every input x, M terminates after at most T(|x|) steps.

• If x ∈ L, then Pr_t∈({0,1})^p(|x|))[M accepts ] > 1/2.

• If x not in L, then Pr_t∈({0,1})^p(|x|))[M rejects ] ≥ 1/2

Where Pr_(t∈{0,1})^p(|x|) means the probability, for a give t from the set {0,1}^P(|x|), that M accepts the input  is greater than 1/2. 
This is similar to the definition of bounded error probabilistic polynomial time(BPP), except that the definition for BPP have both equalities as ≥, so I'm 
guessing I need to show that the language L is in BPP. But how would I even start the proof to show that he language is indeed in BPP. Also the definition of a language in BPP is not identical to what is mentioned in the question, so maybe there's a different approach to answering the question. Also, I don't need to explicitly find the polynomials p and T, but instead argue that they exist.

Any help to assist me with the question would be much appreciated

Comment: I think this question is off topic here. It would probably be more appropriate in Programmers or Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: I vaguely remember this stuff.. so take what I say here with a grain of salt.  i) Check out the Halting Problem this looks like it might be it to me, ii) If it's not I'd proceed by induction.  Prove for n=1, then prove for n+1 given there exists a solution for n.